# The reading of お母さん

Tags: kanji

beginner in Japanese here.
I was curious about why you read the Kanji in お母さん (O**kā**san) differently from just 母 (Haha). I know that there's Kun and On reading but I can't find this Kanji read as "kā" in both readings.

Answer (score 3):

Kun: はは (haha, 母, Jōyō); はわ (hawa, 母); は (ha, 母); あも (amo, 母); おも (omo, 母); かか (kaka, 母); かあ (kā, 母) from wiktionary https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%AF%8D [Etymology 7 has more information on the かあ reading.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%AF%8D)